# Fisheye Undistortion Model

Tags: fisheye

I am trying to understand a fisheye model explained [here](https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/202559089-How-are-the-Internal-and-External-Camera-Parameters-defined-#gsc.tab=0). This fisheye model has been used by Sequoia for its multi-spectral camera.

It is my understanding that given C,D,E,F i.e. parameters of affine matrix and coefficients of polynomial *[p1,p2,p3,p4]*, one can undistort an image taken from that camera. However, I am still unable to see how can I do that. I would be very thankful if somebody can explain me the undistortion process or point me towards some literature for this purpose.

Comment: In case somebody else is also having the problem, please refer to https://support.pix4d.com/hc/en-us/articles/202559089-How-are-the-Internal-and-External-Camera-Parameters-defined-#gsc.tab=0

This link has everything to produce undistortion. However, I am still not sure about the equation (9)